# How can I print a non UTC timestamp using datatable (DT package) in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have some timestamps stored in different time-zones that I would like to include in a datatable using `DT` package within a `rmarkdown` document.

I would like to display the timestamp in the stored time-zone but for some reason `datatable` converts it to UTC. The behaviour when I use `print` is what I want but the format is not nice.

How can I achieve the same behaviour with `datatable` and `print`?

Here a minimal working example of the `rmarkdown` file:

````
---
title: "MinorQ"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(DT)
df=data.frame(timestamp=as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 12:34:56",tz="CET"))
df$tzone=attr(df$timestamp,"tzone")
datatable(df)
print(df)
```
````

Comment: This happens because of the type conversion from R to JS. You could just store the strings: `timestamp = format(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 12:34:56", tz = "CET"), format = '%F %T %Z')`

Comment: Yes, I believe I could also use as.character. When I asked, I was thinking about a more complex case with a couple of time-zones in the data. However, I don't think that situation will arise, so I will go with your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you could just convert your POSIXct elements to character:

```
input <- format(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 12:34:56", tz = "CET"), format = '%F %T %Z')
str(input)

# chr "2017-01-01 12:34:56 CET"
```

This does not mean that you cannot use different timezones. When reading from the table you could use `gsub` to get your dates with the correct timezone:

```
# First gsub: remove all capital letters (so only date and time remain)
# Sec.  gsub: remove all characters exept capital letters (so only CET, UTC, etc. remain).

out <- as.POSIXct(gsub(input, pattern = "[A-Z]", replacement = ""), 
                  format = '%F %T', 
                  tz     = gsub(input, pattern = "[^A-Z]", replacement = ""))

str(out)
# POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-01-01 12:34:56"

lubridate::tz(out)
# [1] "CET"
```